# Как создать ссылку с кодом?

Tags: php

1. Надо создать ссылку site.ru/activation(тут md5)
2. перейдя на данную ссылку надо получить этот md5

Comment: `$_GET[......]`

Comment: Либо так: site.ru/activation/(тут md5) либо site.ru/activation?m=(тут md5) Получить сам код, как выше ответили через $_GET

Comment: а нельзя тупо site.ru/activation=(тут md5) без m?